# How to speed up vector initialization c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, optimization, vector, initialization

I had a previous question about a stack overflow error and switch to vectors for my arrays of objects.  That question can be referenced here if needed: [How to get rid of stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594934/how-to-get-rid-of-stack-overflow-error)

My current question is however, how do I speed up the initialization of the vectors.  My current method currently takes ~15 seconds.  Using arrays instead of vectors it took like a second with a size of arrays small enough that didn't throw the stack overflow error.

Here is how I am initializing it:

in main.cpp I initialize my dungeon object:

```
dungeon = Dungeon(0, &textureHandler, MIN_X, MAX_Y);
```

in my dungeon(...) constructor, I initialize my 5x5 vector of rooms and call loadDungeon:

```
Dungeon::Dungeon(int dungeonID, TextureHandler* textureHandler, int topLeftX, int topLeftY)
{
    currentRoomRow = 0;
    currentRoomCol = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < MAX_RM_ROWS; ++r)
    {
        rooms.push_back(vector<Room>());
        for (int c = 0; c < MAX_RM_COLS; ++c)
        {
            rooms[r].push_back(Room());
        }
    }
    loadDungeon(dungeonID, textureHandler, topLeftX, topLeftY);
}
```

my Room constructor populates my 30x50 vector of cells (so I can set them up in the loadDungeon function):

```
Room::Room() 
{ 
    for (int r = 0; r < MAX_ROWS; ++r)
    {
        cells.push_back(vector<Cell>());
        for (int c = 0; c < MAX_COLS; ++c)
        {
            cells[r].push_back(Cell());
        }
    }
}
```

My default cell constructor is simple and isn't doing much but I'll post it anyway:

```
Cell::Cell() 
{ 
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    width = 16;
    height = 16;
    solid = false;
    texCoords.push_back(0);
    texCoords.push_back(0);
    texCoords.push_back(1);
    texCoords.push_back(0);
    texCoords.push_back(1);
    texCoords.push_back(1);
    texCoords.push_back(0);
    texCoords.push_back(1);
}
```

And lastly my loadDungeon() function will set up the cells.  Eventually this will read from a file and load the cells up but for now I would like to optimize this a bit if possible.

```
void Dungeon::loadDungeon(int dungeonID, TextureHandler* textureHandler, int topLeftX, int topLeftY)
{
    int startX = topLeftX + (textureHandler->getSpriteWidth()/2);
    int startY = topLeftY - (textureHandler->getSpriteHeight()/2);
    int xOffset = 0;
    int yOffset = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < MAX_RM_ROWS; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < MAX_RM_COLS; ++c)
        {
            for (int cellRow = 0; cellRow < rooms[r][c].getMaxRows(); ++cellRow)
            {
                xOffset = 0;
                for (int cellCol = 0; cellCol < rooms[r][c].getMaxCols(); ++cellCol)
                {
                    rooms[r][c].setupCell(cellRow, cellCol, startX + xOffset, startY - yOffset, textureHandler->getSpriteWidth(), textureHandler->getSpriteHeight(), false, textureHandler->getSpriteTexCoords("grass"));
                    xOffset += textureHandler->getSpriteWidth();
                }
                yOffset += textureHandler->getSpriteHeight();
            }
        }
    }

    currentDungeon = dungeonID;
    currentRoomRow = 0;
    currentRoomCol = 0;
}
```

So how can I speed this up so it doesn't take ~15 seconds to load up every time.  I feel like it shouldn't take 15 seconds to load a simple 2D game.

**SOLUTION**
Well my solution was to use std::vector::reserve call (rooms.reserve in my code and it ended up working well.  I changed my function Dungeon::loadDungeon to Dungeon::loadDefaultDungeon because it now loads off a save file.

Anyway here is the code (I got it down to about 4-5 seconds from ~15+ seconds in debug mode):

```
Dungeon::Dungeon() 
{ 
    rooms.reserve(MAX_RM_ROWS * MAX_RM_COLS);
    currentDungeon = 0;
    currentRoomRow = 0;
    currentRoomCol = 0;
}
void Dungeon::loadDefaultDungeon(TextureHandler* textureHandler, int topLeftX, int topLeftY)
{
    int startX = topLeftX + (textureHandler->getSpriteWidth()/2);
    int startY = topLeftY - (textureHandler->getSpriteHeight()/2);
    int xOffset = 0;
    int yOffset = 0;
    cerr << "Loading default dungeon..." << endl;
    for (int roomRow = 0; roomRow < MAX_RM_ROWS; ++roomRow)
    {
        for (int roomCol = 0; roomCol < MAX_RM_COLS; ++roomCol)
        {
            rooms.push_back(Room());
            int curRoom = roomRow * MAX_RM_COLS + roomCol;
            for (int cellRow = 0; cellRow < rooms[curRoom].getMaxRows(); ++cellRow)
            {
                for (int cellCol = 0; cellCol < rooms[curRoom].getMaxCols(); ++cellCol)
                {
                    rooms[curRoom].setupCell(cellRow, cellCol, startX + xOffset, startY - yOffset, textureHandler->getSpriteWidth(), textureHandler->getSpriteHeight(), false, textureHandler->getSpriteTexCoords("default"), "default");
                    xOffset += textureHandler->getSpriteWidth();
                }
                yOffset += textureHandler->getSpriteHeight();
                xOffset = 0;
            }
            cerr << "     room " << curRoom << " complete" << endl;
        }
    }
    cerr << "default dungeon loaded" << endl;
}

Room::Room()
{ 
    cells.reserve(MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLS);
    for (int r = 0; r < MAX_ROWS; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < MAX_COLS; ++c)
        {
            cells.push_back(Cell());
        }
    }
}
void Room::setupCell(int row, int col, float x, float y, float width, float height, bool solid, /*std::array<float, 8>*/ vector<float> texCoords, string texName)
{
    cells[row * MAX_COLS + col].setup(x, y, width, height, solid, texCoords, texName);
}

void Cell::setup(float x, float y, float width, float height, bool solid, /*std::array<float,8>*/ vector<float> t, string texName)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    this->solid = solid;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); ++i)
        this->texCoords.push_back(t[i]);
    this->texName = texName;
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations on? The standard library containers are _templates_ and they benefit greatly from compiler optimizations.

Comment: @Blastfurnace how do I turn them on?

Comment: Try a flat, one-dimensional vector, accessed in strides. Also, `reserve` enough space ahead of time.

Comment: It depends on the compiler. If you use `g++` then add the option `-O2` when you compile. If you use Visual C++, the option is `/O2` on the command line or in the project settings. Note that there are several optimization options, these are just common choices.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2010 then make sure you are building in `Release` mode instead of `Debug` and optimization should be enabled by default.

Comment: What are the values for MAX_RM_ROWS & MAX_RM_COLS?

Comment: well building in release mode its pretty much instantaneous.  Also MAX_RM_ROWS = 5, MAX_RM_COLS = 5, MAX_ROWS = 30, MAX_COLS = 50

Comment: It's still silly to say `rooms.push_back(Room());`. If you just want something default-constructed, use `resize` and don't loop at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems wasteful to have so many dynamic allocations. You can get away with one single allocation by flattening out your vector and accessing it in strides:

```
std::vector<Room> rooms;

rooms.resize(MAX_RM_ROWS * MAX_RM_COLS);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != MAX_RM_ROWS; ++i)
{ 
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j != MAX_RM_COLS; ++j)
    {
        Room & r = rooms[i * MAX_RM_COLS + j];
        // use `r`       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----<< strides!
    }
}
```

Note how `resize` is performed exactly once, incurring only one single allocation, as well as default-constructing each element. If you'd rather construct each element specifically, use `rooms.reserve(MAX_RM_ROWS * MAX_RM_COLS);` instead and populate the vector in the loop.

You may also wish to profile with rows and columns swapped and see which is faster.

Comment: there anyway you coudld explain 'Room & r = rooms[i * MAX_RM_COLS + j];' a little further?  Not quite sure whats happening there.

Comment: @Flappy: I'm just enumerating a two-dimensional space with a single counter. It's the way you would count off cells in a rectangle going row by row and wrapping around.

Comment: let me take a stab at this... So when you get to that line, you are creating a new room called 'r' that points to the current column location. The result of [i * MAX_RM_COLS + j] 0-4 is in row 0, 5-9 is in row 1, so on and so forth.  So it just acts like a 2D array.  I take it I would use 'r' to manipulate the rooms in the array?  Example: r = Room(); (for default init)?

Did I pass? lol

Comment: Hm, no. Everything is already constructed, thanks to `resize`... I just spelt `r` out as an example, but you can use `rooms[...]` directly.

Comment: I can't even call rooms.resize(MAX_RM_ROWS * MAX_RM_COLS); I get a vector subscript out of range

Comment: In the end this is the one I got to work the best.  I ended up using rooms.reserve(MAX_RM_ROWS * MAX_RM_COLS) and it cut it down to a couple seconds after refining some more of the code. Which I will put in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Since it seems that your vectors have their size defined at compile time, if you can use C++11, you may consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of `std::vector`. `std::array` cannot be resized and lacks many of the operations in `std::vector`, but is much more lightweight and it seems a good fit for what you are doing.

As an example, you could declare `cells` as:

```
#include <array>

/* ... */

std::array<std::array<Cell, MAX_COLS>, MAX_ROWS> cells;
```

**UPDATE:** since a locally defined `std::array` allocates its internal array on the stack, the OP will experience a stack overflow due to the considerably large size of the arrays. Still, it is possible to use an `std::array` (and its benefits compared to using `std::vector`), by allocating the array on the heap. That can be done by doing something like:

```
typedef std::array<std::array<Cell, MAX_COLS>, MAX_ROWS> Map;
Map* cells;

/* ... */

cells = new Map();
```

Even better, smart pointers can be used:

```
#include <memory>    

/* ... */

std::unique_ptr<Map> cells;
cells = std::unique_ptr(new Map());
```

Comment: I get a stack overflow error using arrays as I initially stated in the question.

Comment: @Flappy Were you using C++11 arrays or plain C-like arrays? They are totally different things.

Comment: @Flappy A plain C-like array is not an object, but just a data type. `std::array` is an STL class, just like `std::vector`, but the size of the array cannot dynamically change as it is the case of the vector. `std::array` was recently introduce in C++11, so you need a relatively new compiler. Here you have a description of the [new C++11 features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). You can find the link describing `std::array` in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, internet is acting up.  And I will check out the std::array and see how that goes.  How do I know if I can use c++11?  I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional from dreamspark

Comment: @Flappy I had a look at your previous post in SO, and you were effectively using plain C-like arrays. What compiler are you using? If your compiler supports C++11, it might be worth to try using `std::array`, since it will most probably significantly reduce the execution time, plus it will be as safe as using a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Flappy I believe VS 2010 supports some of the C++11 features. You can check whether it supports `std::array` by creating a small program. For instance, something like: `#include <array> int main() { std::array<int, 5> a; a[0] = 1; }`. If it compiles, it means your compiler has support for C++11 arrays.

Comment: my compiler does not support C++11 as I cannot use std::array

Comment: Oh I was missing the include!  Silly me!  I will try this out.

Comment: Unfortunately, `std::array` is a template wrapper around a plain array and not dynamically allocated. If raw arrays were too big for automatic storage then `std::array` will have the same problem.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Well, it is always possible to allocate the array on the heap with `new` (or even better, using a smart pointer). In such a way you would get rid of that limitation.

Comment: That's true but if you are going to use dynamic allocation then `std::vector` and a one-time call to `resize()` or `reserve()` might make more sense.

Comment: @Blastfurnace You are right there, but unless you use flat vectors (simulating 2D by using offsets), you will need to create the inner vectors for each row in the outer vector. `std::array` will reserve all the space at once, so it might be more efficient.

Comment: stack overflow error using std::array as blastfurnace said would happen. It was definitely faster though.

Comment: I agree with you and I prefer `std::array` over raw arrays myself but @Flappy should understand that simply replacing raw arrays with `std::array` might not fix his stack overflow problem.

Comment: @Flappy As I was mentioning, you may want to consider allocating the arrays on the heap. That will fix the stack overflow problem, while most probably will keep the performance benefits compared to using vector. I will update my answer to reflect this possibility.

Comment: Nice update.  I would just have to make sure I clean up using `delete[] cells;` ?

Comment: @Flappy Not if you use smart pointers (e.g., `std::unique_ptr`), but yes, you would need to call `delete` on `cells`. Actually, you would use `delete` (not `delete[]`) since `new Map()` allocates a single object of type `std::array`. For, plain C-like arrays, you would use `new[]` and thus you would need to use `delete[]`, though.